# Transform Samsung smart TV app to work in browser

Tags: javascript, porting, samsung-smart-tv

We have the package of an app built for a Samsung SmartTV. Since we need to preview the app and for some reason we cannot install the emulator on workplace computers we thought of transforming the app in a proper web app to be run in the browser.

I noticed from the code that this should not be impossible. Just some functions should be disabled and mouse and keywords should work instead of remote.

But converting it manually it's a troublesome work.

We were therefore wondering if there is some kit that wraps the samsung API and let the app work on a browser with minor changes.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want your app start work in browser - i recommend manual refactor your code to works in browser. Use "try catch" where you call samsung api. Like that:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var widgetAPI;

    try {

        widgetAPI = new Common.API.Widget();
        widgetAPI.sendReadyEvent();

    } catch (e) {

        // do something in browser version
    }

    Backbone.history.start();
});
```

And you can use CSS pseudo classes like :hover. Don't forget, that apps working with 1280x720px default resolutions, but browser works in different resolution.

Comment: The problem is exactly that we don't have time to refactor everything. I hope there's a snippet to override at one time the SmartTV api with web javascript functions (like remote control) or safe failback for specific functions.

Comment: i don't know something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen any snippet for this. But basicaly you should:

1. Remap keyCode in keydown events (Samsung's keyCode's different from browsers)
2. Make placeholder objects for Samsung's `Common.API.Widget` and `Common.API.Plugin`

If you use player object, it will not work in browser.

If your app uses Samsung UI Framework elements, not sure if it can be launched in browser.